# Making a 3D model compatible for printing

Tags: mesh

I am trying to print an object that is not currently printable because either the edges are too thin or it is not manifold.

Is there a way to thicken the edges and/or make it manifold?

The object is the canopy from the BSG Viper Mark II from this set of files:
https://www.printables.com/model/305304-viper-mkii-battlestar-galatica

Answer (score 0):

There is the [3D Print Toolbox](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/3d_print_toolbox.html) addon.
It has a "Make Manifold" function that should get you most of the way there.

There may be some instances of the function breaking the mesh in certain areas iirc that require manual intervention.